# JavaScript loop within template

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make this work but I am clearly doing something wrong which I can't figure out:

```
function template(data){

  var contentString = 
    '<div id="content">'+
    '<div class="left">'+
    "<div class='icon'><img src='assets/image/cloudy.png' /></div>"+
    '</div>'+
    '<div class="right">'+
    '<p class="temp">'+data.currently.temperature+'</p>'+
    '<p class="summary">'+data.daily.summary+'</p>'+
    '</div>'+
    '<div class="day_wrapper">'+

    for(i = 0; i < data.daily.data.length; i++){
       '<div class="day"><p>'+data.daily.data[i].temperatureMax+'</p></div>'+
    }

    '</div>';

    return contentString;

}
```

Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token for

How can I fix this?

How would I add a 'last' class to the last paragraph in the loop?

Comment: You  can't do that. You need to do `contentString += ` inside your for loop. Remove the `+` just before the loop and add `contentString += ` before your last `div`.

Comment: you can't use for while concatenating. End you concatenate before the `for` loop , continue inside it, then continue after it. I also would strongly advice the use of a templating framework like mustache.js for example...

Comment: have you considered using [templates](http://handlebarsjs.com/) - this stuff gets ugly fast

Comment: Hi all, yes I have considered using handlebars or underscore, however at the moment I am only playing around with data coming from the API.

Comment: fair enough; looks like @harshboss has a precise answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
function template(data){

  var contentString = 
    '<div id="content">'+
    '<div class="left">'+
    "<div class='icon'><img src='assets/image/cloudy.png' /></div>"+
    '</div>'+
    '<div class="right">'+
    '<p class="temp">'+data.currently.temperature+'</p>'+
    '<p class="summary">'+data.daily.summary+'</p>'+
    '</div>'+
    '<div class="day_wrapper">';

if(data!=undefined && data.daily.data.length > 0)
{
        for(i = 0; i < data.daily.data.length; i++){
    contentString +=    '<div class="day"><p>'+data.daily.data[i].temperatureMax+'</p></div>';
        }
 }  


contentString += '</div>';

    return contentString;

}
```

Comment: `contentstring = contentstring + (bla)` is unefficient. Use `contentstring += (bla)` instead.

Comment: But please you also need to check data as undefine or not null

Comment: Sorry i am still fairly new to data coming from APIs, what is the benefit of checking if data is undefined or null? :O

Comment: if there is not any data comes from api then it will come exception. so for handle that exception or strong coding side must check as data coming as undefined or not ?

Comment: If data is null then its not read data.daily.data.length line

Comment: So, if you're going to check that `data` is defined, you should probably also be checking that all the structures you're referencing within `data` are also defined. E.g. `if (data && data.daily && data.daily.data && ...` :-/

As for why you do this, it's good practice to insure you're not trying to reference a property on an undefined or null object (in this case, `data`).  The only reason you wouldn't do that is if you know for sure that data (and all it's sub-members) are going to have the expected [defined] properties.

Comment: How would I be able to add a class to the last paragraph?

Comment: See, when you write the code then you must know about output of that response which you are calling, so from server side if response success then its okay with data.daily.data   bla bla bla as per your object information. undefined need to check for just to make sure as response come valid and sucess or not ?